# nuxt render header.vue with store data

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

i have header.vue with user information from store(vuex) , like username and his img. everything works good when you just work in website clicking on links, but when you reload page, header with this information disappears and appears with a some delay after rendering main components and in header some seconds you can see only login, register buttons. how can i fix this? i have tried to add tags `<no-ssr>` but this is not the best solution, since the page is simply rendered without a header and only after a couple of milliseconds it appears

Comment: Please give us a [repro] if you want a more in-depth debugging here.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have some loading content cannot really be shortened by magic. You could block the rendering of the page with [`asyncData`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#client), that way your app will wait for the HTTP calls to be finished before rendering the page (works only on pages btw).

Also, if you wrap your code inside of the `<client-only>` tag (not `<no-ssr>` because this one is deprecated), what you're asking here is pretty much: "please do not render this part on the server but let my client do the work". Which is mainly the opposite of what you're trying to achieve here.

You could also try to server-render the content being loaded if it's possible, that way it will be visually available even if not hydrated yet.